# Batch File / Cron Job

Tags: php, filesystems, cron

I have 80 Php scripts that I want to run. I want to Start **Script1** wait until its finish starts **script2** ...

Now, if I add the following :

```
start C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f C:\xampp\Script1.php
start C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f C:\xampp\Script2.php
start C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f C:\xampp\Script3.php
```

When I execute my Batch file it will run all scripts at the same time.

Is there any command I could use in my bat file to tell the system wait until script is done then execute the one after? 
Anyway to set a time interval between scripts ?

I could run all 80 scripts in the cron tab, However, Id rather configure one batch file to handle all the scripts then assign this file to the crontab.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you create one PHP file that calls all those files sequentially?

Comment: you're firing up individual tasks and setting them "free" with start. remove the start call and you'll get sequential execution. or do it with windows command chaining: `php ... && php ... && php ...`

Comment: Could you point please into the best way doing that? Which function shall be used.. is ther any tutorial on the web for similar task?
Thanks Joseph

Comment: surely 1 script that accepts an argument, do you really need 80 separate files?

Comment: Im not a developer Dagon, learning that's why You post here. THanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`start` fires off the tasks asynchronously, thus they will all run at the same time. Use the `/wait` flag to start the task and wait for it to complete.

e.g.

```
start /wait C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f C:\xampp\Script1.php
start /wait C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f C:\xampp\Script2.php
start /wait C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f C:\xampp\Script3.php
```

Alternately, as Marc B states, removing the start call should give you sequential execution as well.

Comment: Yes, Djungelrom. I have just tried Marc's approach and the scripts run one after the other. Can this be achieve with a time interval?

Comment: The `TIMEOUT` command will let you insert a time interval; offhand I forget the options available. Your windows installation should have it installed already, although older windows versions needed a resource kit install to get it.

Comment: Thanks again, I have windows 7. I will try all the approaches, I had a look into Joseph's comment and I could create a single php file to call scripts. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As Joseph Sibler suggests, you could craft a single PHP file that calls them sequentially.  You could even generate that PHP file using something like xargs (available on windows w/ mingw32, cygwin, and probably other sources).

Something like this ought to do it:

```
del single.php
dir /b Script*.php | xargs cat >> single.php
start c:\xampp\php\php.exe -f single.php
```

Comment: Thanks Burlyearly. I will have a look at it. Appreciate the help